# How do I create a new column showing difference between maximum date in table and date in row?

Tags: sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, datediff

I need two columns: 1 showing 'date' and the other showing 'maximum date in table - date in row'.
I kept getting a zero in the 'datediff' column, and thought a nested select would work.

```
SELECT date, DATEDIFF(max_date, date) AS datediff
     (SELECT MAX(date) AS max_date
       FROM mytable)
FROM mytable
GROUP BY date
```

Currently getting this error from the above code : mismatched input '(' expecting {, ';'}(line 2, pos 2)
Correct format in the end would be:

```
    date    |   datediff
--------------------------
2021-08-28  |     0
2021-07-26  |     28
2021-07-23  |     31
2021-08-11  |     17
```

Comment: Move the subquery into the DATEDIFF call. Or JOIN it.

Comment: Use `max(dt) over ()`. Or move the whole scalar subquery in line with the expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the date difference, you can use:

```
SELECT date, DATEDIFF(MAX(date) OVER (), date) AS datediff
FROM mytable
GROUP BY date
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using the analytic function MAX() Over()

```
SELECT date, MAX(date) OVER() - date FROM mytable;
```

[Tried this here on sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/efae0/1)

Comment: needs this in oracle form over() doesnt exist in it